# Can't install PhoneGap plugin

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using phonegap 3.2.0-0.17.1
And I'm trying to use this plugin: https://github.com/devgeeks/PhoneListener
Which allows to capture the PhoneState intent.
I've done everything said in the installation explanation except for the adding the line to `plugins.xml` because I don't have this file, I found another example on the internet on how to add the plugin to `config.xml` using this line: `<gap:plugin name="org.devgeeks.PhoneListener"/>`
But when I try to build the project I get this error:

```
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling Android...
   [error] An error occurred while building the android project.Error executing
"ant debug -f C:\Development\myfirstapp\platforms\android\build.xml":
BUILD FAILED
C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The following error occur
red while executing this line:
C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the c
ompiler error output for details.

Total time: 3 seconds
```

Anybody knows what is the solution for this issue?

Comment: What do those lines and compiler output say?

Comment: @Will you mean the 720 and 734? Here:  
720:  
`<do-only-if-manifest-hasCode elseText="hasCode = false.   Skipping...">`  
735:
 `<src path="${source.absolute.dir}" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked the code and this plugin is not adapted to work in phonegap 3.2.0. Find for another plugin or try to refactor the code.
This is an other repo and how adapt the code for cordova > 3

https://github.com/madeinstefano/PhoneStateChangeListener/issues/3

Comment: Thanks.. I assume this code has a syntex error or it uses some deprecated functions? Is there a way to see the exact error of why this doesn't compile?

Comment: A lot of things: `Plugin` class as been replaced by `CordovaPlugin` and the package is no more `org.apache.cordova.api.*` ...

Comment: No no.. What I meant was is there a way to see the actual error?  Because `BUILD ERROR` is not very informative..

Comment: @EphiGabay You can run the ant command that is mentioned in the error message you got: ant debug -f C:\Development\myfirstapp\platforms\android\build.xml and see the exact javac error ant got when trying to build your app. In my case, the problem was that the app name I gave was in Hebrew, the PhoneGap generated ".java" file with no name. To fix it, I had to rename the app to an English name, delete the android folder (under platforms), and build again.